# Edit on Low Quality Posts

Tags: support, editing, review, rollbacks

When reviewing a Low Quality Post I accidentally edited it when, of course, you should only do this if you think you can fix the post, because after an edit the queue moves on. (The edit was just to show what's expected with MathJax, as they were a new user.)

The user had reputation $1$ and had posted a question on another users question, so after editing I would have recommended deletion. Anyhow my edit stopped the deletion process.

So what now; is there any way I can reverse my edit by rolling back (guessing this would change the edit but not the problem), or can the "answer" be reflagged again, finally can a Moderator sort things out, as I don't want it stuck there because of my slip-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you rollback, consider the fact that your edit may have taught the OP something no matter what. So even if the question is still going to be put on hold and/or deleted, I wouldn't recommend a rollback unless you think your edit actually made the question *worse*.

Now what you can always do is vote to close the question (unless you voted to close it earlier and retracted afterwards). It may look a bit puzzling to the OP that you edit the question and then vote to close it, but then again you're not really doing anything wrong.

Comment: Right, thanks. Rollback won't accomplish anything, but I won't bother editing posts that I deem worthy of closing because as you say it looks a bit odd doing so, and they can learn all this as they go along. So how do I vote to close? The problem I had was after I edited, the queue had moved on leaving me no chance to recommend close. Is the best thing to do reflag the question with 'not an answer'.

Comment: I'm slightly unsure how this works. At the moment it has $12$ flags remaining. What do those $12$ flags indicate, does it have to be flagged $12$ times before it can go into the LQP queue, then at what stage does it finally get closed? i.e., once someone flags the question with any of the options it at some point goes into the Low Quality Posts review queue, and then has to gain a sufficient number of close recommendations.

Comment: @DanielBuck No, **you** have 12 flags remaining, meaning that you can vote $12$ times before the end of the day. The post will get closed as soon as it collects $5$ close votes, or one close vote from someone with a gold badge of one of the associated tags.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So I just flagged the question as 'not an answer', does this mean it now **immediately** goes into the LQP queue due to my flagging it, upon which it can go through the review process again, (I should add I'm here guessing thinking it was my edit that messed things up in the first review as it didn't get deleted when it should!) or does something else happen?

Comment: @DanielBuck I don't really understand how you can flag a *question* as "not an answer". Yes it does go immediately into LQP queue. But voting to close a question would move it to the Closing Votes reviewing queue just as well.

Comment: Sorry, yes that makes no sense. I meant I flagged the answer to the question as "not an answer" because it was a *question*, hence the need for deletion. Thanks for your help, you've cleared up what I needed to know.